# How to send a Post request using javascript with headers and parameters?

Tags: javascript, post

I am trying to send a post request using Javascript, but the problem is that I do not seem to be able to add custom headers to the request.

**The request that I want to send:**

```
OPTIONS /startScan?domain=asite.com&user=38 HTTP/2
Host: MYHOST
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Authorization: A_TOKEN
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

note that MYHOST and A_TOKEN are in my case other values, but replaced them for security reasons.

**The request that I send:**

```
OPTIONS /startScan?domain=asite.comm&user=38 HTTP/2
Host: MYHOST
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

The code that I use to send this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "domain": "asite.com",
    "user": 38
    });

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "MYHOST/startScan?domain=asite.com&user=38");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "A_TOKEN");

    xhr.send(data);
```

**The problem:**

The problem now is that I am not able to add a custom header to this request. Instead of adding a header that is called Authorization I add a Access-Request-Control-Header which has authorization as value. I have tried using jQuery, XHR (as you can see) and Fetch, but no success with all of them.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried axios? it's a simple and easy to use library

Comment: Putting your code verbatim in a fiddle results in an xhr that has `Authorization: A_TOKEN` in its headers.

Comment: @ChrisG How would this look like? I am quite unexperienced with Javascript

Comment: What do you mean? Like I said, I used your code verbatim: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfsk5prc/ (note that in browser requests are subject to CORS, so the server has to allow it)

Comment: @ChrisG How can it be that when I catch the request using BURP that it does not create a header in the request?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. If you inspect the xhr in the fiddle you can see all the headers, and the ones you added are in there. What is the issue exactly? What is the server response? Are you getting error messages? Does your server allow cors?

Comment: @ChrisG The problem is that when I use the code posted in the post and I catch the request with BURP Suite to inspect it. I miss a Authentication header (like the one with the paragraph 'request that I want to send').

Comment: I don't know about that but again, as you can see when you inspect the xhr in the browser's dev tools, the headers are all there. Afaik an OPTIONS request is a pre-flight request which only allows certain headers, so it might be missing from that and only be in the actual POST request. But I can only guess.